# file upload rename rand.ext

Tags: php, image, upload, rename

I have a script that runs to upload an image, then resize it into two different images, one is a 540px wide image and the other is a 154px wide image. The script has been running fine for me until i go to rename the files!

i would like to completely rename the file to be a random number followed by the original extension.

i have the random number followed by a . in the variable $ran2 and the original file extention in the variable $ext - i believe i have anyway!

it was working until i wanted to add the rename in towards the bottom of the script!

i believe it is this part that is going wrong: <-- i havent got the file extension in a variable!

```
$filename = "uploads/original/". $ran2.$ext;
$filename1 = "uploads/thumbs/". $ran2.$ext;
```

but i havent got the foggiest idea what to change it to to make it work!

```
<?php 
error_reporting(0);

$change="";
$abc="";


 define ("MAX_SIZE","800");

 $ran = rand () ; 
 $ran2 = $ran."."; 

 function getExtension($str) {
         $i = strrpos($str,".");
         if (!$i) { return ""; }
         $l = strlen($str) - $i;
         $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
         return $ext;
 }

 $errors=0;

 if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
 {
    $image =$_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];


    if ($image) 
    {

        $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['file']['name']);

        $extension = getExtension($filename);
        $extension = strtolower($extension);


 if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png") && ($extension != "gif")) 
        {

            echo 'Unknown Image extension';
            $errors=1;
        }
        else
        {

 $size=filesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);


if ($size > MAX_SIZE*1024)
{
    echo 'You have exceeded the size limit!';
    $errors=1;
}


if($extension=="jpg" || $extension=="jpeg" )
{
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);

}
else if($extension=="png")
{
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$src = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile);

}
else 
{
$src = imagecreatefromgif($uploadedfile);
}

echo $scr;

list($width,$height)=getimagesize($uploadedfile);


$newwidth=520;
$newheight=($height/$width)*$newwidth;
$tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);


$newwidth1=154;
$newheight1=($height/$width)*$newwidth1;
$tmp1=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth1,$newheight1);

imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);

imagecopyresampled($tmp1,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth1,$newheight1,$width,$height);


$filename = "uploads/original/". $ran2.$ext;

$filename1 = "uploads/thumbs/". $ran2.$ext;



imagejpeg($tmp,$filename,100);

imagejpeg($tmp1,$filename1,100);

imagedestroy($src);
imagedestroy($tmp);
imagedestroy($tmp1);
}}

}

//If no errors registred, print the success message
 if(isset($_POST['Submit']) && !$errors) 
 {

    echo 'Image Uploaded Successfully!';
 }

?>
```

Comment: Do you have error reporting on? Do you receive an error?

Comment: i dont see an error because i dont think i have the file extension stripped from the original and stored in the $ext variable

Comment: What do you see when you try and echo $ext

Comment: By the way, take a look at pathinfo: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$ext` is undefined. You have defined `$extension` bot not `$ext`
So, use:

```
$filename = "uploads/original/". $ran2.$extension;
$filename1 = "uploads/thumbs/". $ran2.$extension;
```

Comment: thank you, i knew it was somewhere! its nice to have a fresh set of eyes on it

Answer (score 0):

Try the file name without the "uploads/original/" bit, assuming the script has permissions to create file in the current directory.

if that works, then maybe the path is not found, or you need to escape the "/" character, or the script do not have permissions to create files in those directories.

Also use $extension instead of $ext, and declare it before the If Post statement.